# Recurring task in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a runnable object that is being updated every run (class variables). I want to be able to execute it in a single thread (presumeably SingleThreadExecutor?) **BUT** only after the previous run has completed.

I have tried `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` but it only offers time-based recurring tasks.

Also another problem I encountered that if I schedule the same runnable over and over (in a loop) it runs only once.

How can I acheive what I want?

The class:

```
public class Population implements Runnable{
 private int count=0;
 ...

@Override
public void run(){
    evaluateAll();

    List<Individual> parents = elitism();

    individuals.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < popSize; i++) {
        Individual child = Individual.uniformCrossover(parents);
        if(Utilities.RANDOM.nextDouble() < mrate)
            child.mutate();
        individuals.add(child);
    }

    System.out.println(this);
 }
}
```

The launching part:

```
Population population = new Population();
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors
            .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        ses.schedule(population, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ses.shutdown();
```

Comment: First thing: your Population class probably should not implement Runnable. You want to update the object repeatedly which will likely require using other Runnables and threads.

Comment: One way (though maybe not very beautiful) could be to make the executor known to your population worker. Then the worker thread can use the pool to reschedule itself when it finished its task. But if I understood your problem correctly you only have one worker and this could also be done using an iterative or recursive approach inside the worker method rather than rescheduling the worker thread in order to re-run the whole method?

Comment: you said "runnable object that is being updated every run" - but in your code it is never updated. If it is updated inside the method run(), then just replace run() with a loop with old run() inside.

Comment: it is. individuals is a `List` which gets cleared and repopulated.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just encountered the same requirement and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) looks as if it'll solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run your code in a loop in a dedicated thread

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        for (;;)
            statefulRunnable.run();
    });
}

public static final Runnable statefulRunnable = new Runnable() {
    private int state;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        state++;
    }
};
```

Comment: But then wouldn't the executor be a bit overkill? I could just create a thread with `new Thread(new Runnable(){ ... })` wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, you could. I assumed you might need the `ExecutorService` for other things, like getting a `Future` and cancelling it, instead of `interrupt`ing a `Thread`.

Comment: I'll just go ahead and accept that answer. I may need a different approach. Thanks anyway :)